# C - How to determine the amount of bytes for JSON messages

Tags: c, json, sockets, tcp

I am working on a Linux-based project consisting of a "core" application, written in C, and a web server, probably written in Python. The core and web server must be able to communicate with each other over TCP/IP. My focus is on the core application, in C.

Because of the different programming languages used for the core and web server, I am looking for a message protocol which is easy to use in both languages. Currently I think JSON is a good candidate. My question, however, is not so much about the message protocol, but about how I would determine the amount of bytes to read from (and maybe send to) the socket, specifically when using a message protocol like JSON, or XML.

As I understand it, whether you use JSON, XML, or some other message protocol, you cannot include the size of the message in the message itself, because in order to parse the message, you would need the entire message and therefore need to know the size of it in advance. Note that by "message" I mean the data formatted according to the used message protocol.

I've been thinking and reading about the solution to this, and have come to the following two possibilities:

1. Determine the largest possible size of a message, say 500 bytes, and based on that determine the buffer size, say 512 bytes, and add padding to each message so that 512 bytes are sent;
2. Prepend each message with its size in "plain text". If the size is stored in an Int (4 bytes), then the receiver first reads 4 bytes from the socket and using those 4 bytes, determines how many bytes to read next for the actual message;

Because all of the offered solutions I've read weren't specifically for the use of some message protocol, like JSON, I think it's possible that maybe I am missing out on something.

So, which of the two possibilities I offered is the best, or, am I not aware of some other solution to this problem?

Kind regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must be aware that for TCP/IP you cannot rely on receiving exactly one message. You may as well receive less than one or more than one message as the connection is a stream. You must prepare for reading a part and wait for the remaining part to be received.

Comment: You actually need a high level protocol to be able to gather a full JSON message. But as JSON is text oriented, you could also use special non ascii bytes as message delimiters because they cannot be included in a JSON message.

Comment: Or rather non-Unicode if you're allowing that. If you're going to pick a text encoding, it's best to use utf-8 probably.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Thank you. By message I mean what I, as a programmer, specify to be a message. Say this message size is X bytes. Then, is it not true that you read X bytes from the socket, in a blocking manner, so that when you finish reading, you've read X bytes, which is a message?

Comment: @sudo: JSON encode non ASCII byte in ASCII, so UTF8 should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Vincent there's no correlation in TCP streams between individual calls to read from the socket, and the packets sent over the wire.   TCP itself takes advantage of this with the Nagle algorithm, which very slightly delays transmission of very small packets in case another packet is queued up immediately after.

Comment: @SergeBallesta not true - JSON can carry UTF-8 natively and doesn't encode it specially.

Comment: @Vincent I'd very highly recommend prepending a message length value.  DNS over TCP does this, using a two-byte length field (sent in binary, not text, in big-endian order) for a maximum message size of 65535 bytes.    The minor disadvantage of this is that you must render your data into JSON (i.e. into memory) so you know how long it is before you can start sending it.

Comment: @sudo: You are right for the general case. The Python json module does encode non ascii characters, and json allows such an encoding, but a JSON message could contain any Unicode non control character.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Python 2 strings are ASCII by default, I think. I forget how that works because I always use 3, where strings are Unicode, and the json module does encode Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem encountered with streams, including those of TCP, often called the "message boundary problem." You can search around for more detailed answers than what I can give here.

To determine boundaries, you have some options:

- Fixed length with padding like you said. Unless you have very small messages, not adviseable.
- Prepend with size like you said. If you want to get fancy and support large messages without wasting too many bytes, you can use a variable length quantity, where you use a bit to determine whether to read more bytes for the size. @alnitak mentioned a drawback in the comments I neglected, which is that you can't start sending until you know the size.
- Bound with some byte you don't use anywhere else (JSON and XML are text-only, so '\0' works with ASCII or any UTF). Simple but slower on the receiving end because you have to scan every byte this way.
- Edit: JSON, XML, and many other formats can also be parsed on-the-fly to determine boundaries (e.g. each `{` must be closed with `}` in JSON), but I don't see any advantage to doing this.

If this isn't just a learning experience, you can instead use an existing protocol to do this all for you. HTTP (inefficient) or gRPC (more efficient), for example.

Edits: I originally said something totally wrong about having to include a checksum to handle packet loss in spite of TCP... TCP won't advance until those packets are properly received, so that's not an issue. IDK what I was thinking.

Comment: You don't appear to know how TCP works.   You can't "lose" a packet like that in TCP.   A lost packet will be detected by the operating system and automatically retransmitted.

Comment: My bad, I totally had a lapse and forgot TCP won't advance without receiving the last message. Editing...

Comment: @Alnitak The JSON spec says that control characters must be escaped, if you go to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 and search "except for the characters that must be escaped." The C JSON libraries I've seen use null-terminated strings like many libs in C, and Python gives an error if you try to decode a string containing null bytes.

Comment: I missed the bit on json.org where it says "except control character" !   Either way, I still wouldn't use delimiting in this case.